# what is the command "-bash" after running "ps -aux |grep bash"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I opened terminal and run the command `ps -aux |grep bash` to learn the difference between Login Shell and Non-Login shell on my virtual machine's graphical interfaces (Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 x86).

[image: The output result]

But the output which shows both `bash` and `-bash` made me confused. I googled a lot to find out what the command `-bash` is, but I can only find something about `bash`, so I come for help.

Comment: I think this question belongs to [Unix&Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) and has already an [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81849/309777) there

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour). This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: Thanks and I am sorry. Actually it's my first time to come stack overflow. Now what should I do now? Should I delete this question?

Comment: Normally you should delete the question here and post it again on the other network. But it seems that you have found your solution here. So I would recommend to not delete it (because there is a helpful solution, already). A moderator can migrate your question to Unix&Linux.

Comment: @colidyre Thanks for your explanation. And could you tell me if I should contact with moderator to ask him to migrate this question, or the moderator will do this by himself?

Comment: Maybe you can flag your own question? But I'm not sure how the process of it is exactly. Maybe you can found an answer on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means `bash` is invoked as a login shell. This case it will have a hyphen before its name.

From `man bash`, section INVOCATION:

> A login shell is one whose **first character of argument zero is a `-`**, or one started with the `--login` option.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got it.
But thus I am confused by another thing.  Please see my screenshot on https://imgur.com/a/f4Q2Uhm. 
The area I marked actually shows  two terminals opened in my GUI, I heard such terminals are Non-Login shells, but "-bash" shows they are Login shells. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: @xile See `man bash` section INVOCATION for more information.